# Ibatis out params from stored procedure in Oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis

I have a stored procedure which has three out params all user defined types.
I use ibatis as ORM from java code to call the stored procedure.
How do i configure this stored procedure call in ibatis xml
and how do I get the results back in my java code.
procedure test(
     p_a in int default 0 ,
     p_b in number default 0,
     p_criteria out TBL_A,
     p_baseline out TBL_B,
     p_results out TBL_C);

Any help would be highly appreciated.
thanks,
gagan suri

Answer (score 1):

In your xml configuration provide parameters with in/out mode (jdbcType is optional):

```
<procedure id="callProcedure1" parameterClass="map">
        {
            call procedure1(
                #value1,jdbcType=DECIMAL,mode=INOUT#,
                #value2,jdbcType=DECIMAL,mode=INOUT#,
                #value3,jdbcType=DECIMAL,mode=INOUT#,
                )
        }
</procedure>
```

And in your dao class just get your results from parameters:

```
final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//provide input parameters here
params.put("value1", 1);
AbstractSQLMapDao.queryForObject("namespace.callProcedure1", params);
//retrieve you output
Double value1 = params.get("value1")
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The issue is that the out params are user defined oracle types. what should be their  jdbctype.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. The issue is that the out params are user defined oracle types. what should be their  jdbctype. I tried with the actual oracle type like this jdbcType="TBL_OPTIMSEEDS" typeName="TBL_OPTIMSEEDS" mode="INOUT". But still I am getting error --- Check the output parameters (register output parameters failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type